# ReactJS In a user profile display only fields that have a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

### Objective

Displaying only the fields that are filled in.

## Background

In my application people will first fill out the application which has fields like "early reg fee, early reg date, regular reg fee, regular reg date" and so after they fill out all the information and click "view profile" they will see all the fields whether it's filled out or not.

If the value of one of the fields is null or undefined then it would not show up in the profile.

I was trying to do this and I started of by creating a state in the constructor "this.state {value: ''}"

```
class CompetitionProfileView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state {value: ''}
        this.getContactCard = this.getContactCard.bind(this);
    }

    getCompetitionValue(path) {
        const value = _.get(this.props.competition, path);
        return value ? value : '';
    }

    getCompetitionDateValue(path) {
        const value = _.get(this.props.competition, path);
        return value ? value.toDateString() : '';
    }

    getCompetitionTimeValue(path) {
        const value = _.get(this.props.competition, path);
        return value ? `${
            value.getHours() - 12 
        }:${value.getMinutes()}` : '';
    }

    getContactCard(num) {
        return 
        this.getCompetitionValue(`Information.contactFirstName${num}`) ?
        <Card key={num} style={{backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9', width: '32%'}} zDepth={2}>
        <CardTitle title={`${this.getCompetitionValue(`Information.contactFirstName${num}`)} ${this.getCompetitionValue(`Information.contactFirstName${num}`)}`} subtitle={`${this.getCompetitionValue('Information.contactPosition1')}`} />
       <Divider/>
                      <CardText>
                        <p style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}><Phone/>{`${this.getCompetitionValue(`Information.contactFirstName${num}`)}`}</p>
                        <p style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}><Email/>{`${this.getCompetitionValue(`Information.contactFirstName${num}`)}`}</p>
                      </CardText>
                    </Card>
                :
                    '';
            }

            render(actions) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div className="profileheader" style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                    <Paper className='banner-image' style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.getCompetitionValue('Resources.boardPicture.url')})`,backgroundSize: 'cover',width: '100%', height: '200px', backgroundPositionY: '20%'}} zDepth={3}>
                      {/* <br style={{lineHeight: '15'}}/> */}
                    </Paper>
                    <Paper className='text-main' style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                      <label>{this.getCompetitionValue('Information.name')}</label>
                    </Paper>
                    <Paper className='logo-image' style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.getCompetitionValue('Resources.competitionLogo.url')})`, backgroundSize: 'cover', width: '100px', height: '100px', marginTop: '-110px', marginLeft: '3%', paddingbottom: '20px'}} zDepth={3}/>
                  </div>

                  <hr/>

                  <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                  <Card style={{backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9', width: '49%'}} zDepth={2}>
                    <RaisedButton style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}} primary={true} label="Application Packet" onClick={() => window.open(this.getCompetitionValue('Resources.applicationPacket.url'), '_blank')}/>
                  </Card>
                  <Card style={{backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9', width: '49%'}} zDepth={2}>
                    <RaisedButton style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}} primary={true} label="Audition Video Info" onClick={() => window.open(this.getCompetitionValue('Resources.auditionVideoInfo.url'), '_blank')}/>
                  </Card>
                  </div>

                  <br/>

                  <div className='mainbody' style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                    

                    <br/>

                    <div className='rightbody' style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: '60%', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
                      <Card style={{backgroundColor: '#F0EFEF'}} zDepth={2}>
                        <CardHeader title="About Us" />
                        <Divider/>
                        <CardText>{`${this.getCompetitionValue('Information.compBlurb')}`}</CardText>
                      </Card>
                      <br/>
                      <Card style={{backgroundColor: '#F0EFEF'}} zDepth={2}>
                        <CardHeader title="Application Information" />
                        <Divider/>
                        <CardText>
                          <p><b>Early Reg:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionDateValue('Information.dueDateEarly')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Early Reg Fee:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionValue('Information.earlyDues')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Regular Reg:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionDateValue('Information.dueDateRegular')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Regular Reg Fee:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionValue('Information.regularDues')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Late Reg:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionDateValue('Information.dueDateLate')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Late Reg Fee:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionValue('Information.lateDues')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Applications Due At:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionTimeValue('Information.dueTime')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Time Zone:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionValue('Information.timeZone')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Penalties:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionValue('Information.extraFees')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Hear Back Date:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionDateValue('Information.hearbackDate')}`}</p>
                          <p><b>Payment Method:</b>{` ${this.getCompetitionValue('Information.paymentMethods')}`}</p>
                          <br/>
                        </CardText>
                      </Card>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <br/>

                  <div className="contactinfo" style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>
                    {[1,2,3].map((num) => this.getContactCard(num))}
                  </div>
                   <br/>
                  {this.props.competition.Board.length > 0 &&
                  <Card style={{backgroundColor: '#F0EFEF'}} zDepth={2}>
                  <Table >
                    <TableHeader adjustForCheckbox={false} displaySelectAll={false}>
                      <TableRow>
                        { Object.keys(this.props.competition.Board[0]).map((key) => <TableHeaderColumn key={key}>{key}</TableHeaderColumn>) }
                      </TableRow>
                    </TableHeader>
                    <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
                      {this.props.competition.Board.map((row, i) => (
                          <TableRow key={i}>
                            { Object.keys(row).map((column) => <TableRowColumn key={column}>{row[column].name ? row[column].name : row[column]}</TableRowColumn>) }
                          </TableRow>
                        ))
                      }
                    </TableBody>
                  </Table>
                  </Card>
                  }
                </div>
              );
            }
          }

          const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
            return {
              messages: state.messages
            };
          };

          export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CompetitionProfileView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` statements in your `render()` function, like so:

```
render() {
  if (this.props.thing1) {
    return <h1>Thing 1</h1>
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="warning">
        <h2>Thing 2</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can even use functions in the `render()` function like this:

```
renderASmallPart() {
  if (this.props.thing1) {
    return <h1>Thing 1</h1>
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="warning">
        <h2>Thing 2</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <h2>Here's a thing:</h2>
      {this.renderASmallPart()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can use this to break up your large `render()` function into smaller functions that check what the value of their field is and only render something when the field has a non-empty value

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into Conditional Rendering and only render that element when there is a value.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

https://atticuswhite.com/blog/render-if-conditionally-render-react-components/

http://devnacho.com/2016/02/15/different-ways-to-add-if-else-statements-in-JSX/

https://kylewbanks.com/blog/how-to-conditionally-render-a-component-in-react-native